# Do I need permission for services like Fabric Crashlytics in iOS?

Tags: ios, debugging, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have developed an app which has nice download figures, however when I look at App Statistics on iTunes Connect, I can see that it does crash a couple of times. I'd like to take that out by using a service like Fabric Crashlytics.

What I'm wondering though, and what I can't find a lot of info about, is whether I need to ask my users permission to do this? In the end of the day, the service does send data from their device to a server. Can I just do this in the background or do I need to ask for permission?

Comment: No not required any permission from user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Crashlytics terms https://try.crashlytics.com/terms/

> What information does Crashlytics collect from End Users?
>
> The Services automatically collect certain information that does not
>   personally identify End Users who access or use mobile applications
>   that use the Services. This information includes, but is not limited
>   to, device state information, unique device identifiers, device
>   hardware and OS information, information relating to how an
>   application functions, and the physical location of a device at the
>   time of a crash.

Answer (score 2):

It is not mandatory, but you should ask your users to collect these datas. [Here](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/349914-can-i-toggle-whether-or-not-a-user-needs-to-give-p) you can see how to do this.

Edit:

[Go here](http://crashlytics.com/settings/apps) to select the app you want to add the dialog to and
then click on "Enable Privacy Prompt" in the top left corner.

Answer (score 1):

Simply upload new build with integration of Fabric Crashlytics. Your app does not need any permission from user to track analytics data or crash reports.

Crashlytics sends you symbolicated crash logs, so you can get exact idea on which line your app getting crashed.

You can find more about Re - Symbolication and Crash Analytics in this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33669/overview-of-ios-crash-reporting-tools-part-1).

Follow this link to know more about [Crashlytics](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/crashlytics/crashlytics.html).

Comment: What is your source that says that you don't have to ask the user for permission?

Comment: As i am already using it in my Apps to get daily crash report.

Comment: So your real statement is, that you don't ask the user in your app. But you don't have any source that says that there is no legal requirement not to ask the user.

Comment: Hi @technerd, Thanks for commenting. I do agree with Kerni that it might be more convenient to have an actual source stating that no permission is needed. Do you know anything like that?

Comment: If any of you find any document or link regarding user permission then please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @technerd if you're asking for legal requirements, you'd probably better tell us which jurisdictions you're thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

Crash report and iTunes Analytics is not the same thing.

If all you care about is the crash report you can access it via Xcode without need for the Fabric Crashlytics service.

Just open the Xcode organizer and on the AppStore build select crash reports